# Routing in angularjs ,$routeParams.energyId undefined

Tags: angularjs, routes

Here is the problem the $routeParam prints to the consol two times that is , **Object {}** and the **object** with params.I want to access the params that outputs error becuase it is accessing the $routeparam's **Object {}** state.

how could i solve this.

can you please elaborate becuase here i printed it to the cosole in the conroller one time but it is displaying two values that means it is excuting two times. I used current parms but it doesnt help here is my code .
I want to get the params.

```
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ngRoute', "ngAnimate", "ngAria", 'ngMaterial']);


    myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/:energyId/:energyChain/:resourceId/:facilityId',
        {
            templateUrl: '/Content/resourceTemplate.html',
            controller: 'detailsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/param1/param1/param1/param1'
        });

    }]);

    myApp.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {

            console.log($routeParams);
```

[image: Inspection output]

Comment: This can happen when controller gets loaded twice. Can you check if there is a controller declaration such as `ng-controller='detailsController'` in your view.

Comment: thanks men,It worked glamorously ah it took me days to figure routing problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack this by adding routeChangeEvents.

**Example:**

```
 myApp.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$route',function ($scope, $routeParams,$route) {

 $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            console.log($routeParams);
}
```

Comment: thanks men,It worked glamorously ah it took me days to figure routing problems